# Matrix equation solving

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

I have these matrices given:

$$A= \begin{bmatrix} 
   3&1&1&1\\1&2&0&{-1}\\0&1&2&{-1}\\0&0&1&1\end{bmatrix}$$

$$T= \begin{bmatrix} 
1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&{-1}\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

$$C= \begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3\\0&1&2\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

And I have to find matrix $B$ for which the following equation is true:
$${ABC=4AT+2BC}$$

so far I managed to get this:
$${B=4AT(A-2I)^{-1}C^{-1} }$$

But I got a problem with $AT$, because it cannot be multiplicated. Help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Why not? $A$ is $4 \times 4$ and $T$ is $4 \times 3$. In addition note that matrix multiplication is not commutative, so you might want $B=(A-2I)^{-1}4ATC^{-1}$ instead.

Comment: Oh right,i made a miscalculated.

Comment: And by the way,can you check if i isolated B correctly?

Comment: It was a typo, my bad. It is $(A-2I)$

Comment: And i know it is not commutative,so first i managed to get 2BC on the left side and then i got BC isolated at first and got inverse of $(A-2I)$ on the right side and after the same with C

Comment: You got $(A - 2I)BC = 4AT$. Multiply _from the left_ by $(A-2I)^{-1}$, and you get $BC = (A-2I)4AT$. Not the other way around.

Comment: I made a mistake with $BC$ okay i get it now, thankyou very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the matrix mathematics:
$$ABC=4AT+2BC$$
Pass $2BC$ to the left-hand side, preserving order (because it matters):
$$ABC-2BC=4AT$$
Factor out the $BC$ because matrix multiplication does not commute: $AB \neq BA$
$$(A-2I)BC=4AT$$
Right-multiply $C^{-1}$ to remove $C$ from the left-hand side:
$$(A-2I)B=4ATC^{-1}$$
Left-multiply $(A-2I)^{-1}$ to remove $(A-2I)$ from the left-hand side:
$$B=(A-2I)^{-1}4ATC^{-1}$$

Comment: Since I is the identity matrix, A-2I is only subtracting two to the elements in the diagonal of A, whereas A-2 is subtracting 2 to all elements of A. Shouldn't it be A-2O, where O is a matrix filled with ones?

Comment: @Alex, you are right. Sorry about that. Fixed it! :)

Comment: $2X = (2I) X$, not $(2O) X$. @Alex: In matrix algebra, have never seen the notation $A-2$ used to mean anything other than $A-2I$, and that's certainly what's needed here.

Comment: @Alex, I think he's right.